# Port 9300 on Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

According to the documentation, [Elasticsearch reserves port 9300-9400 for cluster communication](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-transport.html) and [port 9200-9300 for accessing the elasticsearch APIs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html). You get the impression that these ranges are *inclusive*: so port 9300 is part of the first and the second port range.

Now, my IT ops department won't like that, so hopefully I got it wrong. Anyone knows?

Comment: Your IT department is thinking in a `subnet` where the first and last IP address is not used (they are the network and broadcast IP), but you are thinking about a `range` which is just a bunch of contiguous IP addresses.

Answer (score 42):

Elasticsearch will bind to a single port for both HTTP and the node/transport APIs.

It'll try the lowest available port first, and if it is already taken, try the next. If you run a single node on your machine, it'll only bind to 9200 and 9300.

See also: [Elasticsearch Internals: Networking Introduction](https://www.found.no/foundation/elasticsearch-networking/)